# ARMv5 and earlier MOV and MVN operands

Tags: assembly, arm, mov, arm7, immediate-operand

**NOTE:** Question refers to ARMv3 (1993-2001) and is valid for ARMv5 (approximately 2006).  It is not relevant to cell phone developers or most modern ARM CPUs.  Some embedded devices may have this ISA.

I'm trying to write code to do two things: return a 1 to register r2 if my value is presentable as a constant in the ARM data processing instruction. This code does that (offer better methods if it's inefficient please). However, I also want to modify it to tell me whether a MOV or MVN needs to be used.

```
    AREA    ArmExample18b, CODE

        ENTRY
            MOV r2, #0                          ;register return value. if =1, representable, otherwise, not representable      
            LDR r1, TABLE1                      ;input value we want to use
            LDR r3, TABLE1+4                    ;upper bound register
            LDR r4, TABLE1+8                    ;lower bound register
            MOV r5, #12
            
INVCHECK    CLZ r6, r1                          ;r6 contains number of leading zeros in r1
            RBIT r7, r1
            CLZ r8, r7                          ;r8 contains number of trailing zeros in r1
            CMP r6, r8
            SUBCS r9, r6, r8
            RSBCC r9, r6, r8
            CMP r9, #8
            MVNHI r1, r1
            BHI INVCHECK
            BLS LOOP
LOOP                                
            CMP r3, r1                          ;compare input value with upper bound
            BLO STOP                            ;if bigger than u.b, stop, r2 = 0 
            CMP r4, r1                          ;compare input value with lower bound
            MOVLS r2, #1                        ;if larger than lower bound, it falls within range, set r2 = 1
            BLS STOP                            ;then stop
            CMP r4, #0                          ;if r4 has reached 0, then we are at the end of comparisons and can stop
            BEQ STOP
            LDR r3, TABLE1 + r5                 ;change upper bound
            ADD r5, r5, #4          
            LDR r4, TABLE1 + r5                 ;change lower bound
            ADD r5, r5, #4          
            B LOOP
STOP        B STOP


TABLE1  DCD 0x500, 0x3fc0, 0x1000, 0xff0, 0x400, 0x3fc, 0x100, 0xff, 0
    
    END
```

Comment: Not sure what you'd want `MVN` for(?). Do you mean `MOVHI`?

Comment: No, I mean MVN. The question is to modify the program to tell me whether MOV or MVN needs to be used.

Comment: @Notlikethat I'm using ARM7, but have never heard of those. I'm guessing they invert each bit?

Comment: `CLZ` = "Count Leading Zeroes", `RBIT` = "Reverse Bits" (where "reverse" means the order of bits in the value, not the individual bits' values). `RBIT` followed by `CLZ` is effectively a "Count Trailing Zeroes" operation, which is not directly available.

Comment: Just googled them, let me see what I can do

Comment: I've edited it, but any ideas how to update the register that tells me whether MOV or MVN is needed?

Comment: @Notlikethat clz and rbit also don't work for me. Are there any other methods you can think up?

Comment: Related: thumb-mode allows repeated-bit-pattern immediates (somewhat like arm64 bitwise logical instructions) for some instructions, as well as the 8-bit-rotated form.  [How can ARM's MOV instruction work with a large number as the second operand?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26762878).  e.g. `return x | 0x01010101` can compile to a single `orr` instruction with `gcc -O3 -mthumb` but not `-marm`: https://godbolt.org/z/a77Wj1q6b

Answer (score 3):

> However, I also want to modify it to tell me whether a MOV or MVN needs to be used.

Test for the `MOV` case.  If no, test for the `MVN` case and set a flag (or whatever your API wants).  Often people use +1 (MOV), 0 (can not fit), -1 (MVN) as this might be nice to test in the caller pure ARM.

---

Being completely ignorant, I started by investigating what **gas** (GNU assembler does).  I found the answer in [tc-arm.c](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gas/config/tc-arm.c#l7268) in a routine called `encode_arm_immediate()`.  Here is the source,

```
/* If VAL can be encoded in the immediate field of an ARM instruction,
   return the encoded form.  Otherwise, return FAIL.  */

static unsigned int
encode_arm_immediate (unsigned int val)
{
  unsigned int a, i;

  for (i = 0; i < 32; i += 2)
    if ((a = rotate_left (val, i)) <= 0xff)
      return a | (i << 7); /* 12-bit pack: [shift-cnt,const].  */

  return FAIL;
}
```

Some interesting points.  It is not very efficient like your example, but it is more correct.  I don't think you are handling constants like *0xf000000f* which can be represented.  Also, the code in `move_or_literal_pool()` in the same file has this pseudo code,

```
if((packed = encode_arm_immediate(val)) == FAIL)
    packed = encode_arm_immediate(~val);
```

It is pretty clear that if you have a test for `MOV`, you can complement and test for `MVN`.  In fact, I don't think you will be more efficient by trying to test each in parallel as you complicate the logic too much.  The current steps can be minimized with an instruction to find the first set bit (`clz`) as you don't need to iterate over all of the bits [see [pop_count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736602/fastest-way-to-count-number-of-1s-in-a-register-arm-assembly)()].

```
 bits = pop_count(val);
 if(bits <= 8) {
    /* Search 'MOV' */ using clz to normalize */
    shift = clz(val);
    val =<< shift;
    if((val & 0xff<<24 == val) && !shift&1) goto it.
    if((val & 0xfe<<24 == val) &&  shift&1) goto it.
    /* test for rotation */
 }
 if(bits >= 32-8) {
    /* Set 'MVN' flag */
    /* as above */
 }
```

There are various ways to implement a *population count* and/or run of numbers.  Really, if your algorithm is **correct** and handles the rotation, the simple `encode_arm_immediate()` seems like it's simplicity will end up being very competitive to any solution that tries to use advanced instruction to detect runs of bits.  The `encode_arm_immediate()` will fit in the cache and the loop will be running quickly on an ARMv7 with caches and branch prediction.

Comment: For *runs of numbers* take a look at the bit twiddling `(x-1)&~x` type code.

Answer (score 3):

[@artlessnoise has provided a thorough explanation of the way to go about it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27968479/3156750) (that's the 'real' answer IMO), but since this piqued my interest I fancied solving it from scratch. On an ARM7, you don't have all the fancy bit-manipulation instructions of later architectures, but it turns out they're a bit of a red herring here. The straightforward "try every valid rotation until you find one which fits in 8 bits (i.e. <=255)" approach came out to some beautifully compact idiomatic assembly (GNU flavour as I couldn't convince the armcc toolchain to play nicely):

```
.syntax unified
.cpu   arm7tdmi
.globl    testconst
testconst:
    mov   r2, #32
1:  mov   r1, r0, ror r2
    cmp   r1, #255
    movls r0, #1          @ using EABI registers for the sake of this example
    movls pc, lr
    cmn   r1, #256        @ no good? how about the inverted version then?
    movhs r0, #-1         @ note that we'll still have the separated 
    movhs pc, lr          @  value and shift parts in r1 and r2 when we
    subs  r2, #2          @  return - those might come in handy later
    bne   1b
    mov   r0, #0
    mov   pc, lr
```

With this little test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int testconst(int);

void test(int c) {
    int r = testconst(c);
    printf("%i (%08x) %s\n", c, c,
           r > 0 ? "fits MOV" :
           r < 0 ? "fits MVN" :
           "doesn't work");
}

int main(void) {
    test(0);
    test(42);
    test(-42);
    test(0xff);
    test(0x1ff);
    test(0x81);
    test(0x10001);
    test(0xff << 12);
    test(0xff << 11);
    test(~(0xff << 12));
    test(~(0x101 << 12));
    test(0xf000000f);
    test(0xf000001f);
    test(~0xf000000f);
    test(~0xf800000f);
}
```

To give the expected results:

```
/ # ./bittest
0 (00000000) fits MOV
42 (0000002a) fits MOV
-42 (ffffffd6) fits MVN
255 (000000ff) fits MOV
511 (000001ff) doesn't work
129 (00000081) fits MOV
65537 (00010001) doesn't work
1044480 (000ff000) fits MOV
522240 (0007f800) doesn't work
-1044481 (fff00fff) fits MVN
-1052673 (ffefefff) doesn't work
-268435441 (f000000f) fits MOV
-268435425 (f000001f) doesn't work
268435440 (0ffffff0) fits MVN
134217712 (07fffff0) doesn't work
```

Hurrah!