# How to know that a certain number can be represented as 32 bit immediate in ARM?

Tags: assembly, arm, immediate-operand

Given a number x, how can we tell that it can be represented as 32-bit immediate. 
Does any kind of formula exists? If yes, is that formula exhaustive, i.e., covers all the possible cases? ARM decomposes the rightmost 12 bits in the instruction set as 4 bit rotate-bit and 8 bit value bit.

Comment: I would think that you can just test whether the population count (number of 1 bits) is <= 8 ?

Comment: Which instruction do you mean? http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473e/Chdcegci.html -- "using LDR Rd, =const", so if it does not "fit", the assembler should place it in a literal pool, so I don't see restrictions there.

Comment: Count the distance between the first and last '1' bit (with wrapping allowed). If it's less than 8, then it'll work.

Comment: @PaulR: That would allow `0xF000F000`, which can't be represented as `imm8 ROR n`.

Comment: @Michael: yes, just realised that - thanks - useful tool here: http://alisdair.mcdiarmid.org/arm-immediate-value-encoding/ (scroll down to bottom of page)

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27963312/3156750) - although we only really discuss brute-force checking there rather than cleverer algorithms.

Comment: how you know is read the arm documentation infocenter.arm.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into open source compilers and how they do it...

https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/cbca62831cb7c1c7c20d67fcf929f156b09923bf/gcc/config/arm/arm.c#L4387

```
/* Return TRUE if int I is a valid immediate ARM constant.  */
int
const_ok_for_arm (HOST_WIDE_INT i)
{
...
```

Comment: Note that the gcc source is also checking for more modern ARM `mov` immediate encodings which  allow for '0xAB00AB00' and '0x00AB00AB' type constants.  There is also a great [ARM blog on constants](https://community.arm.com/groups/processors/blog/2010/07/27/how-to-load-constants-in-assembly-for-arm-architecture) which might be helpful to readers.  The 'gas' assembler might be better as it needs to decide whether `ldr rX,=xxx` will be a `mov` or an `ldr rX,[pc,#offset]`.